# How do I embed a video using html5?

Tags: html, html5-video

Hello I'm building a webpage I've got everything else but i don't know how to embed a video using html5? This is very important in my website so help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Youtube has some info (https://www.youtube.com/html5) also here are the  basics (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)

Answer (score 5):

Before HTML5, videos could only be played with a plug-in (like flash).
The HTML5  element specifies a standard way to embed a video in a web page.

```
 <video width="420" height="340" controls>
  <source src="sample_movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="sample_movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

The `controls` attribute adds video controls, like `play, pause, and volume`.

It is a good idea to always include `width` and `height` attributes.

If `height` and `width` are not set, the browser does not know the size of the video. The effect will be that the page will change (or flicker) while the video loads.

Text between the `<video>` and `</video>` tags will only display in browsers that do not support the  element.

The `src` attribute can be a URL of the audio file or the path to the file on the local system.
Multiple `<source>` elements can link to different video files. The browser will use the first recognized format, In other words, it will pick the first one which works for it. In the above case, if it recognizes `type="video/mp4"` it will pick that one instantly. (Usually happens to beat the different versions of browsers).
If you wish to start a movie automatically, simply use the `autoplay` attribute like this:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For a deeper read: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Answer (score 5):

```
<video id="myMovie" width="640" height="360" poster="video.png"  >
     <source src="20140810_131405.mp4">
</video>
```

using the video tag.  The poster attribute is the thumbnail pic.  Obviously the source links to the actual video file.