# I want to include a .mov file on my website

Tags: javascript, html, video, mp4

I have a video in a .mov format. The problem is video has a very high resolution and has a 2GB size.
I want to include it on a section from my website and I want to ask what is the best method for that? I was thinking for an iframe, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I embed a video using html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032035/how-do-i-embed-a-video-using-html5)

Comment: You'll have to convert to MP4. What's the audio & video **codecs** inside the MOV? Check using a tool like **MediaInfo**. If the video is H264 and the audio is **AAC** then conversion means copy/pasting the a/v data into an MP4 container. If audio or video codec is not one of those types then you'll have to re-encode. After converting to MP4 then upload to your website's storage. Use a `<video>` tag to display the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
 <source src="path/to/your/video" type='video/mov'>
 </video>
```

Or try:
`<iframe src="path/to/your/video" width="400" height="300"></iframe>`